# Why is a Merge process via ArcObjects extremely slow?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, c#, geoprocessing

In one of my arcobjects-based GIS tools I have a process which takes an array of shapefile paths and uses them as inputs with the [ESRI.ArcGIS.DataManagement.Merge](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//0047000038zs000000) tool. I run it via a [Geoprocessor](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/Members/004700002t2p000000/) instance. I use this setup for various other gp tasks (such as Get Count and Calculate Field), but I have found that a Merge process takes a much longer period to process than if I had run it in ArcMap or ArcCatalog. For example, a process which I have clocked at around 3 hours took **over 27** to complete when performed with this method in ArcObjects.

Has anyone experienced this before, and are there any known methods for expediting the process?

**EDIT**:
To be more explicit about the workflow taking place here:

1. Create a backgroundworker object to do this in a separate thread to avoid UI lockup.
2. List shapefile paths using Directory.GetFiles and append them to a semicolon-delimited path string for the merge operation
3. Perform a Get Count on each Shapefile
4. Use the path string to perform a merge operation.

I've tried using `IGeoProcessor` and `Geoprocessor` to see if there is any noticeable increase in performance, but to no avail. There are no tight loops involved (unless you consider rapid-fire Get Counts), and I certainly have no use for an EditSession. For some reason, however, the process just plods along at an amazingly slow pace.

It is worth noting that I am working with unreasonably large data sets (the road network of North America, for example), so I doubt any method that makes use of RAM as a workspace will be appropriate.

Comment: I wonder if you have a memory leak somewhere. If you monitor resource consumption in your tool and in arcmap, how does it compare?  Are you calling [IGpUtilities3.ReleaseInternals](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/ReleaseInternals_Method/002n0000048t000000/) anywhere?

Comment: My memory and process use never goes above a certain amount, but I have not measured it versus ArcMap. It certainly stays below what usually constitutes a memory crash of the program. I'm wondering if the heavy COM marshaling might be stacking up to slow me down. Have you ever run into a problem like that, Kirk?

Comment: Did you start an EditSession (i.e called StartEditing), that for sure would do it. Take a look at this answer I gave before: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8186/performance-of-arcgisscripting-and-large-spatial-data-sets/9060#9060

Comment: Let me be more explicit about the process of the code-- but as a quick answer, no I did not start an edit session. I've yet to use an edit session when working with ArcObjects.

Comment: Have you considered using Append instead of Merge?

Comment: I have considered methods for doing this process in smaller steps-- but that does not speak to the difference in processing time between ArcObjects and ArcMap/Catalog.

Comment: Yeah I am not sure what the difference is there either. Have you tried running your process from a STA command line application? May be some penalty for using a backgroundworker. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model#Threading_in_COM

Comment: I don't think I'll be able to use an STA command line app because it has to be run from a GUI for the convenience of the end user.

Answer (score 2):

You could try setting an [in-memory workspace](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//001m0000002q000000) to reduce I/O write times, as this may be slowing your process.

See an example of the SetEnvironmentValue() method below for using an in-memory workspace, assuming you've already set it up.

```
        Dim GP As New Geoprocessor
        Dim StreamLink As New StreamLink

        StreamLink.in_stream_raster = inStreamRaster
        StreamLink.in_flow_direction_raster = inFlowRaster
        StreamLink.out_raster = outRaster

        GP.SetEnvironmentValue("workspace", WorkspacePath)
        GP.TemporaryMapLayers = False
        GP.AddOutputsToMap = False
        GP.ClearMessages()
```

Comment: At what point would an in-memory workspace improve the time? I'm merging dozens of gigs of data, so how would I put them in the workspace? Or are you suggesting I create the workspace for an output? Again, I do not believe my RAM, large as it is, could even begin to handle this file.

Comment: I've edited my answer to show an example of how you might go about implementing an in-memory workspace using the Geoprocessor in ArcObjects. Your RAM very well may be a limitation. You could always go the hardware route and look into a solid-state drive.

Comment: That is an idea, and it is a bit sad that we're still using HDDs, but the storage cost would be monumental. All that aside, I still wish I knew why running the process inside ArcWhatever makes it go so much faster.